# Default style lost (e.g. colors) after setting custom style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, telerik, treeview

I use the `RadTreeView` from telerik to show a tree with nodes. To bind the `IsExpanded` Property to my own IsExpanded property I use the following snippet:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type telerik:RadTreeViewItem}" x:Key="ItemContainerStyle"  >
    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding Path=IsExpanded,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</Style>
```

This works fine so far but the highlight color of the nodes turned from blue into grey. How can I keep the original style and only add the setter property?

EDIT:

I use the telerik `Windows8Theme` and adjust the `Windows8Palette`.
Before adding the mentioned style element in XAML the color of a selected element was the AccentColor (blue) of the Windows8Palette. After adding the style element it seems to use the BasicColor (grey) of the Windows8Palette. I don't know what exactly is going on but comparing the RGB values shows this color switch.

Comment: This sounds like `telerik` is somehow connecting the `IsExpanded` property to the highlight colour. Have you tried looking into the style through blend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the answer. I overwrote our custom style from another assembly. This here works:

```
<telerik:radGridView.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/OtherAssembly,component/existingStyles.xaml />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource xKeyOfStyleToExtendFromExistingStyles}" TargetType="{x:Type telerik:RadTreeViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding Path=IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </Style>
  </ResourceDictionary>
</telerik:radGridView.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to inherit the style from the default:

```
<Style x:Key="ItemContainerStyle"
       TargetType="{x:Type telerik:RadTreeViewItem}"
       BasedOn="{x:Type telerik:RadTreeViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding Path=IsExpanded,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</Style>
```

The `BasedOn="{x:Type telerik:RadTreeViewItem}"` does tell it to inherit the current default style and just "add" your setter.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. When I add this attribute it says though: "The specified value cannot be assigned. The following type was expected: "Style"".

Comment: So far I have figured out it should be: BasedOn={StaticResource ResourceKey={x:type telerik:RadTreeViewItem}}
This inherits from the telerik default style but overrides a custom theme.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
<Style x:Key="ItemContainerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type telerik:RadTreeViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type telerik:RadTreeViewItem}}">
    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding Path=IsExpanded,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</Style>
```

...if you want to base your custom style on the default one.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. This assures that the telerik default style is used. But I would like to use the same style which was used before adding the Style element. And that was a custom style and not the default telerik style.

Comment: Then you should base the style on this custom style: BasedOn="{StaticResource TheXKeyOfTheCustomStyle}">

Comment: I guess I don't have a StaticResource to base my style on. The problem is that the telerik Windows8Theme we use is not applied correctly to the tree any more when using the XAML style element. For some reason the BasicColor of the Windows8Palette is used and not the AccentColor any more when selecting nodes. See as well my edit in the opening question.